# Why is "onpaste" not recognized as a valid javascript event in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

Is the `onpaste` event a valid javascript event in HTML 5? If so, why does VS 2019 show this error?

[image]

It works absolutely fine. Was just wondering if it is to be deprecated in the future or something.

Comment: perhaps because it's considered experimental [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste) even though every browser (except IE) supports it - maybe microsoft needs to update its HTML5 validation

Comment: Also use oninput since it works too and can replace all your other handlers - or better use `.addEventListener("input",srch)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from onpaste not being standard, I strongly suggest to use oninput since it works too and can replace all your other handlers - or better use
[input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) ([browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_globaleventhandlers_oninput))

> The input event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed.

which includes when something has been pasted into it

```
document.getElementById("yourInputID").addEventListener("input",srch)
```

Comment: Thanks. Will switch to `oninput` immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check canIuse.com to understand which HTML/JS works in what browser.

Look: [click](https://caniuse.com/?search=onpaste).

> This feature is non-standard and should not be used without careful consideration.
> See full reference on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/onpaste).

The `onpaste` is not standard.

Answer (score 1):

`onpaste` is not standard (if it were, it would be listed [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements,-document-objects,-and-window-objects)), but the `paste` event [is standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-paste) (though not universally supported, at least not by older browsers).

This dichotomy reflects the consensus that `onXyz` attribute event handlers are not best practice. Use `addEventListener` to hook up event handlers:

```
document.querySelector("css-selector-for-element").addEventListener("paste", handler);
document.getElementById("id-for-element").addEventListener("paste", handler);
// ...
```

Generally, though, the `paste` event isn't all that useful; [`input`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input) is a more useful event:

```
document.querySelector("css-selector-for-element").addEventListener("input", handler);
document.getElementById("id-for-element").addEventListener("input", handler);
// ...
```

It's fired whenever the input, well, receives input, regardless of the *mechanism* by which it receives input.